# Integer appearing in print line when char assigned

Tags: java

I am trying to get the print line to read "Access Code XXX:" by using a conditional operator. However, it is only giving me "Access Code 888888:". I'm not sure how to properly format the char to show as "X" in the command line instead of "88".

```
public static final int MAX_GUESSES = 15;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rng = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter = 0;
    int digit1 = 5;
    int digit2 = 5;
    int digit3 = 5;
    int inputDigit1 = 12;
    int inputDigit2 = 12;
    int inputDigit3 = 12;
    int accessCode;
    char f = 'X';
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int x3;

    while(counter < MAX_GUESSES) {

        counter++;

        x1 = (inputDigit1 == digit1)?(digit1):f;
        x2 = (inputDigit2 == digit2)?(digit2):f;
        x3 = (inputDigit3 == digit3)?(digit3):f;

        System.out.print("Access Code " + x1 + x2 + x3 + ":");
        accessCode = input.nextInt();

        inputDigit1 = accessCode/100;
        inputDigit2 = (accessCode%100)/10;
        inputDigit3 = accessCode%10;

    }

}
```

Comment: Try changing you data types from int to char (or Strings if digit values are really multiple digit).  You can also try String.valueOf(x1), etc

Comment: If you change the declared type of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` to `char`, you might be able to write something like   `x1 = (inputDigit1 == digit1)?((char) ('0' + digit1)):f;`.